# How to create a responsive two column <ul> with FA icons as bullets in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've been having a lot of trouble with the "Hobbies and Interests" section of my project. See screenshot: [image: Current Section Layout]. Specifically with the unordered list that has font awesome icons as bullets. I want it to be in two columns but be responsive, in that the gap between the columns will adjust and that the icons and text won't shift off into new lines as it is doing currently

```
                 <section id= "skills">


                <h3 class="text-center pt-3 pb-3"><strong> Ready to tackle any challenge. Proven by performance.</strong></h3>
                <div class="container containerPadding">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 ">

                            <!--- Instruments -->

</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-2 ">




                            <div class="container float-center">
                                    <h1 class="text-center pt-5 ez-animate" data-animation="bounce"><strong>Hobbies and Interests</strong></h1>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col" style="column-count: 2; column-gap: 15em;">
                                        <ul class="barbie list-unstyled">
                                            <li class= "barbieitem pb-2 pt-2 puzzle text-left ">Puzzles</li>
                                            <li class= "barbieitem pb-2 pr-4 plane text-left">Travel</li>
                                            <li class= "barbieitem pb-2 wrench text-left">Handy Work</li>
                                            <li class= "barbieitem pb-2 plane text-left">Travel</li>
                                            <li class= "barbieitem pb-2 volunteer text-left">Volunteering</li>
                                            <li class= "barbieitem pb-2 car text-left">Automobiles</li>
                                            <li class= "barbieitem pb-2 plane text-left">Travel</li>
                                            <li class= "barbieitem pb-2 camera text-left">Photography</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </section>
```

CSS:

```
     dt {font-size: 1.3em;position:relative;}
     dt:not(:first-of-type) {margin-top: 2em}

     dt:before {
        content: ""; 
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        left: -40px;
      // position:absolute;
        top: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 8px;







    }

    dt.achievement:before {
        content: "\f091"; 

        //These two nested lines control the FA Icon animation! because of the fact i am using a ::before element, I cannot use the native fa spinning classes explicitly in the html
        -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
        animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
    }

      dt.academic:before {
        content: "\f19d"; 
    }


    dd {margin-left: 0}
    dd.description {font-size: 1.2rem;}
    dd.subdescription {
      font-size: 1rem;
      font-weight: 700;
    }

         li.puzzle::before {
      font-family: "FontAwesome";
      font-size: 1.1em;
      content: "\f12e";
      margin-right: 8px;
      display: inline-block;
      -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
      animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
    }
    li.wrench::before {
      font-family: "FontAwesome";
      font-size: 1.1em;
      content: "\f0ad";
      margin-right: 8px;
      display: inline-block;
      -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
      animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
    }
    li.plane::before {
      font-family: "FontAwesome";
      font-size: 1.1em;
      content: "\f072";
      margin-right: 8px;
      display: inline-block;
      -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
      animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
    }
    li.car::before {
      font-family: "FontAwesome";
      font-size: 1.1em;
      content: "\f1b9";
      margin-right: 8px;
      display: inline-block;
      -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
      animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
    }
    li.volunteer::before {
      font-family: "FontAwesome";
      font-size: 1.1em;
      content: "\f0c0";
      margin-right: 8px;
      display: inline-block;
      -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
      animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
    }
    li.camera::before {
      font-family: "FontAwesome";
      font-size: 1em;
      content: "\f030";
      margin-right: 8px;
      display: inline-block;
      -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
      animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
    }

    @keyframes fa-spin {
      0% {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg);
      }

      100% {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
          transform: rotate(359deg);
      }
    }


    .shift{
        margin-left:20px;
    }

    .barbie{
      list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        color: rgba(59,66,76,1);
    }

    .barbieitem{
      //text-align: right;
      font-size: 1.2em;
    }

 .jarallaxTextResize{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .jarallaxTextResize{

    //font-size: 4rem;
    font-size: 2.8rem;
}

}

.jarallax {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
      }
    .jarallax > .jarallax-img {
        position: absolute;
        object-fit: cover;
        /* support for plugin https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images */
        font-family: 'object-fit: cover;';
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
      }
    /* Help from: https://free.nkdev.info/jarallax/*/
    .overlay {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      height: 75vh;
      background-color: rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.6);
    }
    @media only screen and (max-height: 740px) {
      .overlay {
          height: 100vh;
      }
    }
    .overlay-cell {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      //top: 35%;
      top: 34%;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    /*.heroSection {
      height: 100vh; //Controls the height of the Hero
    }
    */

    .subSection {
      height: 300px; //Controls the height of the subsection jarallax
      //margin: 0;
    }

    .overlay-cell.header {
      top: 115px;
  }
```

Comment: How do I center the actual <ul> though so that the gap is aligned in the middle? If I center text, the icons look ugly, and the first column is too far to the left...?

Comment: [mcve] You forgot the **minimal** part.

Comment: Hi rob, this includes the relevant code to this section of my project in case there are conflicts... do you have a solution  you can suggest?

Comment: I suggest you create a minimal example of the problem. [mcve]

Comment: @Rob I made the changes to the HTML. Now its cleaner. I would now appreciate your code suggestion to get the effect I want

Comment: I suggest you read the helpful link I gave you and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The text/icon is wrapping because you have a fixed width of 15 of the current font characters.  Because of the column-gap rule you set, the rest of the div needs to reflow around this. Try adjusting or getting rid of column-gap and you will likely get closer to the result you want.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, that seems to fix part of the issue, though  I remember that the reason I had such a large padding was b/c I couldn't figure out to center the entire <ul> itself, accounting for the FA Icon, but keeping the <li> left aligned. Any ideas how to do this?